# Static member doesn't exist within const func<T,T>

Tags: c#, function, static

This is possibly a very obvious logical question but I can't seem to wrap my head around why the static member Char.ToUpper(char) should cease to exist within the code below.

```
    private const Func<Enum, string> getString = vdEnum =>
    {
        var str = vdEnum.ToString().ToLower().ToCharArray();
        str[0] = Char.ToUpper(str[0]);
        return new string(str);
    };
```

My code is fully functional and works fine should I declare this func to be a "static readonly" member of the class however I would greatly appreciate an explanation of const that would help me understand why the above code should not compile in VS 2013 because of the error:

> "Cannot resolve symbol 'ToUpper'

Yet when I change this func to a "static readonly" it compiles fine?

Thank you in advance for any help you may offer.

Comment: Why not use an extension method?

Comment: @ja72 Presumably because he needs a delegate for whatever it is that he's doing, not a static method.

Comment: @ja72 What I've missed here is that Linq statements are not compile time literals, so a static extension of Char wouldn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `const` can only be assigned a compile time literal.  You're not assigning a compile time literal, so this has no chance of working.  One would hope for a different error message, but in this case the code that you're providing is so far from what the compiler is expecting that you don't get a great error message.  The solution, as you have already noted, is to not use `const` here and instead make it a readonly field.